# Show most relevant pages

Tags: laravel

I want to show most relevant pages of day, that pages with more clicks in links ordering by clicks. With eloquent relationship...

I got a table

> clicks {page_id, created_at}

And I got a table

> pages {id}

How can I create a relationship with two tables?

Controller:

```
 ...
```

Model:

```
...
```

Data:

```
whereDate('created_at', today())
```

I don't know, help me, I'm beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Define the `hasMany` relationship in the `Page` model:

```
public function clicks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Click::class);
}
```

Then use the [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method to count links:

```
Page::withCount(['clicks' => function($q) {
        $q->whereDate('created_at', today());
    }])
    ->latest('clicks_count')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Is with more clicks in link in the day, ordering by clicks desc, not more links...

Comment: @ValterSousaCardoso just change `links` to `clicks`. These are just names, the principle is the same.

Comment: Now I want to show the pages ordering by clicks, how can I do it?

Comment: @ValterSousaCardoso I've already given you the code for this. `->latest('clicks_count')` does sorting.